# One word for all kinds of reading materials

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

What's the word or phrase for all kinds of reading materials like books, magazines, journals, newspapers etc?

Comment: I think you've already used one of the best and most common ones which is "reading materials". The other is the very similar "reading matter".

Comment: Another might be texts? Are you referring only to published material, not letters, diaries, manuscripts, etc? Also, click on "single-word-requests" and read what it says.

Comment: You need to provide a sentence showing how you want to use the word. Are you trying to distinguish hard copy from digital? Published from unpublished? Does an advertising brochure count?